# Unnest array of rows with a tagged column

Tags: postgresql, set-returning-functions, timescaledb, postgresql-14

I'm trying to create a query that will return data in this format:

| id | time | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2.5 |
| 1 | 2 | 3.5 |
| 1 | 3 | 6.4 |
| 2 | 1 | 8.3 |
| 2 | 2 | 8.5 |

I'm using Timescaledb and wish to use one of their downsampling functions for each unique id

```
select
        id,
        asap_smooth(time, value, 80)
from
        data
group by
        id
```

Where the `asap_smooth` aggregate function returns a custom datatype that can be unnested without the id into the following format:

```
SELECT * FROM unnest(
    (SELECT asap_smooth(time, value, 80)
     FROM data));
```

| time | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2.5 |
| 2 | 3.5 |
| 3 | 6.4 |

Is there anyway to get each row tagged with the id it belongs to? I've tried this query however I can't seem to unpack the record type into their own columns:

```
select
    id,
    unnest ((select asap_smooth(time, value, 80))) t
from
    data
group by
    id
```

| id | t |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {1,2.5} |
| 1 | {2,3.5} |
| 1 | {3,6.4} |
| 2 | {1,8.3} |
| 2 | {2,8.5} |

Comment: So do you have your answer?

Answer (score 1):

The [type `Timevector`](https://docs.timescale.com/api/latest/hyperfunctions/downsample/asap/) is unlike other standard data types in Postgres. Similar to an `array` of <ROW type>, but using a `vector` instead of the `array`, which is otherwise only used in the system catalogs.
Simply decomposing the resulting row type should do it:

```
SELECT id, (unnest(asap_smooth(time, value, 80))).*
FROM   data
GROUP  BY id;
```

But I would rather use this more explicit form:

```
SELECT sub.id, asap_row.*
FROM  (
   SELECT id, asap_smooth(time, value, 80) AS asap
   FROM   data
   GROUP  BY id
   ) sub
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL unnest(asap) AS asap_row ON true;
```

Because the second form preserves rows from the subquery `sub` where `asap_smooth()` returns NULL or an empty set. The first form eliminates such rows. See:

- [Flattening a relation with an array to emit one row per array entry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32001490/939860)

And because of this:

- [How to avoid multiple function evals with the (func()).* syntax in a query?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18370271/939860)

Plus, I am more confident the second form actually works.